# How to understand wallets?

Tags: c++, libbitcoin

I'm trying to generate a mnemonic seed, and everything that goes with that. I'm using c++ / libbitcoin, using the following code - https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/wiki/Examples-from-Addresses-and-HD-Wallets

When I compile & run the following code - get this output

```
Address, WIF, Wallets: 
13ggzjqKyFGQZtxNWUoG4BFDPAgdBijUe4
L5PbbAgFUENjW7XjzPBSMUwtVpV8S62cXq14cwUGDdCq1xt1SiNU
13ggzjqKyFGQZtxNWUoG4BFDPAgdBijUe4
L5PbbAgFUENjW7XjzPBSMUwtVpV8S62cXq14cwUGDdCq1xt1SiNU
1

Mnemonic Word Lists: 
family episode combine ask flee weekend sword spatial vibrant leg style fancy
```

When I take that generated mnemonic and put it in this site - https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

I am getting completely different paymeny addresses.

Digging through the source code of libbitcoin it has very little function documentation & this is the only code sample I could find. So can someone help me generate a wallet in libbitcoin where the data is recognized by other wallets/services? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The address `13ggzjqKyFGQZtxNWUoG4BFDPAgdBijUe4` is generated from a different word list, not the one you mentioned.

Comment: How can I verify that in code - in libbitcoin how do I generate addresses from word lists?

Comment: Check this [wiki](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/wiki/Addresses-and-HD-Wallets).